# How to improve the HTML formatting in Evolution mail client

Tags: linux, email, formatting, html, evolution

I have a question about viewing HTML emails in the [Evolution mail client](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/). Basically, I am receiving some emails that look lovely in Thunderbird but not in Evolution because the HTML rendering of Evolution isn't as advanced.

Here is a screenshot of the difference:

[image]

Does anyone know how to improve the HTML rendering of Evolution? e.g. a plugin, tip, code patch, etc...

The closest I've got is to right-click the email, "Save As...", save as a html file, then open in Firefox. Not exactly streamline!

*What emails can't it display well?* We use the [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) revision control system which is set up to send an [email whenever someone commits](http://www.andywu.co.uk/better_subversion_notification_emails_with_svnnotify.htm) via `svnnotify` all nicely coloured via the `--handler HTML::ColorDiff -d` parameter. When Evolution fails to use the colours, I find it very hard to read the raw diff.

Comment: Good vs. bad screenshots might be helpful.

Comment: @dennis-williamson Thanks for the advice, screenshot added.

Comment: Great question, would love to see the render engine changed. It's all sorts of HTML e-mail that Thunderbird displays perfectly but Evolution messes up...

Answer (score 0):

One *workaround* is to configure `svnnotify` with the `-a` parameter instead of `-d` (*[see svnnotify docs](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/SVN-Notify-2.80/lib/SVN/Notify.pm#attach_diff)*) so that instead of sending a email with the svn diff **inline** in the email, it sends a email with the diff as a email **attachment**. The advantage of this is that I can click on the attachment in Evolution and "Open with gedit", for example ([gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) knows how to syntax hightlight a diff so it is more readable).

*Meta: I won't accept this as a answer, because it is only a workaround. Perferably I'd like to receive the diff inline and have it rendered by Evolution.*

Another workaround is to use Thunderbird for my mail client - but I like Evolution, the killer feature for me is the [contacts sync with Ubuntu-one account](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Contacts).

Comment: Even their website doesn't seem to load right... But maybe report a bug in their bugzilla? It looks like Evolution is not doing CSS styling properly like Thunderbird is.